# KnockoutJS Containerless foreach inside template script

Tags: knockout.js

I have a configuration array that contains field names that I want to show on a page. I can use containerless foreach to render my header row. Then table body is generated in template script. It should print as many rows as there are contacts and also dynamically render some values. Let the code speak:

```js
<div class="w3-padding" data-bind="visible: contacts().length>0">
    <div class="w3-container w3-blue">
        <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-responsive">
        <table class="w3-table-all">
            <tr class="w3-light-gray">
                <th style="width:125px">Full name</th>
                <th style="width:125px">Customer</th>

                <!-- ko foreach: fields -->
                <th style="width:125px" data-bind="text: name"></th>
                <!-- /ko -->

                <th class="w3-center" style="width:125px">Action 1</th>
                <th class="w3-center" style="width:125px">Action 2</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'contactTemplate', foreach: contacts }"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="contactTemplate">
    <tr>
        <td><div data-bind="text: fullname"></div></td>
        <td><div data-bind="text: customername"></div></td>

        <!-- ko foreach: $root.fields -->
        <td><div data-bind="text: logicalName"></div></td>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <td class="w3-center"><button class="w3-button w3-light-blue w3-border w3-round-large" data-bind="click: function(){$parent.createPhoneCallHandler($data)}">Create Phone Call</button></td>
        <td class="w3-center">
            <button class="w3-button w3-light-blue w3-border w3-round-large" data-bind="click: function(){$parent.openContact($data)}">Open Contact</button>
            <button class="w3-button w3-light-blue w3-border w3-round-large" data-bind="enable: $parent.contactHasAccount($data), click: function(){$parent.openAccount($data)}">Open Account</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

So first part of the code prints nice header row dynamically depending on "fields". Btw, fields is just an array of objects like

```
{ name: "Human readable name", logicalName: "machine_name" }
```

In my template I'd like to print value of the given field for each contact, but I can't get it work. If I have it like I have it now, it prints logical name of the field, for example "telephone". But I'd like to have it print value of the telephone property of the contact.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in a nested foreach the context for your contact object is the $parent, so you can change `data-bind="text: logicalName"` to `data-bind="text: $parent[logicalName]"` to get the value.

```js
function viewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.contacts = ko.observableArray([
    { id: 1, address: '123 A street' },
    { id: 2, address: '123 B street' }
  ]);
  self.fields = [
    {name: 'col1', logicalName: 'address'},
    {name: 'col2', logicalName: 'id'}
  ];
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div class="w3-padding" data-bind="visible: contacts().length>0">
    <div class="w3-container w3-blue">
        <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-responsive">
        <table class="w3-table-all">
            <tr class="w3-light-gray">
                <!-- ko foreach: fields -->
                <th style="width:125px" data-bind="text: name"></th>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>
            <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'contactTemplate', foreach: contacts }"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="contactTemplate">
    <tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: $root.fields -->
        <td><div data-bind="text: $parent[logicalName]"></div></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</script>
```